# Rails: receive and send images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing rails application. My task is to show data from old java application. One of the objects has images attached, I have to display these images and allow user to add new ones.

I want to know what is the best way to let user uploading images to old app.

Old app has http post method for adding images with params: multipart file, md5 hash of the image and object id.

I tried using paperclip or carrierwave but their documentation is about saving  uploaded images and I just want to transfer them somewhere else and not save anything.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What do you mean by saying "One of the objects has images attached, I have to display these images and allow user to add new ones." Is this object a database object or api result?

Comment: If your Rails app has to works like an API, you could encode your image to Base64, send it then manage it within your old app

Comment: @ccoeder in database there are objects (geographic locations in this case) and image needs to know id of that object (not important for my problem).

Comment: @adominey I still couldn't understand, do you store that objects in your rails app database or are they coming from an api?

Comment: they are coming from api. I'm getting list of objects from api and want to add images to these objects. nothing is stored in my database.

Comment: okay, so just do what oshan said. You need to make a request to the java api.

Answer (score 1):

there are few ways to communicate with java from ruby.

1. REST API - expose Java functionalities through endpoints. then use an [HTTP client](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty).
2. Remote Procedure Call - [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/)
3. JRuby - embedded java programme into Ruby

however, I think maybe you can just proxy the Java API without going through the rails application.